# extracing 0 values from array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am currently programming an AI for the game [Hex](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(Spiel)). The board is represented by an array of length 121. During the simulation phase of the Monte-Carlo-Tree Search , I  extract the possible moves.

I just loop over the array and extract the index where a 0 value was found. (Possible values are 1,-1,0)

```
std::vector<unsigned char>moveListe;
moveListe.reserve(121 - board->moveCount);
for (unsigned char i = 0; i<121; i++) {
    if (board->board[i] != EMPTY) {
        continue;
    }
    moveListe.push_back(i);

}
```

Is there any way to speed this up ?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @manni66: Sry, I was in a hurry. I edited my text above

Comment: Why do you need to speed it up? If you're having issues with your code under-performing you will probably need a lot more information about why this code doesn't meet your needs and how fast you need it to run.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to extract all positions of zeroe values from STL vector or simple array of length n in time less than O(n). This part of your algorithm should be efficient.